# Transform string to datatype and create generic list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, generics, types

I have tried to create a generic list with different datatypes.

For example, I have an string array:

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] {"integer", "double"};
```

and I want to create a list with the given types in the string.
For example:

```
List<stringArray[0]> intList = new List<stringArray[0]>();
```

but this does not work.

Does anyone know how to do this **without if statements**?

**Edit:**
I just would like to create different lists with different types with a loop. In my example there then would be 2 lists (int and double). If there would be another element e.g called bool. There would be three lists (an int list, a double list and a bool lost)

Comment: Rather unclear, imo. _generic list with different datatypes_ What are you really trying to accomplish? List<T> is the replacement of ArrayList, which can indeed hold different datatypes. There is a reason it is deprecated!!

Comment: I suspect you have an XY problem...

Comment: _"I have tried to create a generic list with different datatypes"_ do they share anything? like an interface? Is it a well defined structure? If so you could wrap it in an object so you know what to expect where and when.

Comment: What do you want to do with if statements ? can you show this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<Type>` would be a better option. The example below creates a collection of `Type` then iterates over the collection creating a new instance of each item.

```cs
// Generic List
var types = new List<Type>();

// Add Types
types.Add(typeof(int));
types.Add(typeof(double));

// Iterate List
foreach(var type in types)
{
    // Dynamically create instances of type
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Insert additional code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
        string[] stringArray = new string[] { "System.Int32", "System.Double" };
        List<object> intList = new List<object>();

        foreach (string tipo in stringArray)
        {
            try
            {
                intList.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(tipo)));
            }
            catch (TypeLoadException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: Unable to load type", e.GetType().Name);
            }
        }
```

But keep in mind the strings must be fulll qualified Types (like "System.Int32")

*If you only need a list of the Types, omit the Activator.CreateInstance()*